# String manipulation using Java

Tags: java, string

I have a

```
String s = "text()=\"123\"]";
```

I tried

```
String[] strArray = s.split("text()="); // it gives me an exception.
```

But when I do

```
String[] strArray = s.split("="); // it works...
```

I am confused why this is happening?

Comment: _What does the exception say_?

Answer (score 5):

The Java String.split(String) method accepts a [Java regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) as the first (and only) parameter.

The string `=` is a valid regular expression.  If you wanted to split on `test()=`, you would need to use:

```
String[] strArray = s.split("test\\(\\)=");
```

Answer (score 3):

[`String#split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression. The string `"text()="` contains parentheses, which have special meaning in regular expressions. Try escaping the parens:

```
String[] strArray = s.split("text\\(\\)=");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) needs a valid regular expression; `text()=` is *not* a valid regular expression, while `=` *is* a valid regular expression.

Comment: @downvoter Care to **explain** your vote, or perhaps point out what in your opinion might be wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this documentation from oracle - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

The java string `split()` function accepts a regular expression.  The parenthesis characters can be known as metacharacters which alter the way the string is split.

Regular Expressions - http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html